# Symfony Related Validation Or Validation Group

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have the following form elements

```
$builder->add('link_to', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Link To *',
    'choices'  => [
        'Session' => 'session',
        'Category' => 'category',
        'External URL' => 'url'
    ]
]);

$builder->add('category', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Category *',
    'class' => \App\Entity\Category::class,
    'choice_label' => 'translations[en].name'
]);

$builder->add('session', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Session *',
    'class' => \App\Entity\Session::class,
    'choice_label' => 'translations[en].title'
]);

$builder->add('url', TextType::class, [
    'label' => 'External URL *'
]);

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'attr' => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        'data_class' => \App\Entity\Banner::class
    ]);
}
```

I want to add `NotBlank()` validator to `category, session or url` field based on the value from `link_to` field, for example, if user has selected `Session` in `link_to` field then `Session` field must be mandatory and so on.

I tried with validation groups and I am getting confused, can someone help me with how to go about this with either validation group or some other approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a custom [validator constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) set for entire Banner class. This was you can enforce complex validation rules based on entire object:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
     $resolver->setDefaults([
         …
         'constraints' => YourValidatorConstraint::class
     ]); 
}
```

If you don't want additional classes you can use the `Callback` constraint:

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
    …
    'constraints' => new Callback(['callback' => [$this, 'validate']]),
]);

public function validate($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    // go bananas
}
```

Comment: I don't have a complex logic here and I think going with custom validator constraint is over kill, I am thinking perhaps callback validator will be the easiest. However I was thinking if this can also be done using validation group.

Comment: Overkill is doing hack magic inside forms which are hard to test, debug and maintain.

Comment: I can see your point, moreover custom validator constraint could be reusable across the app. Thanks for pointing it out and appreciate your help. If it is the CallBack validator then perhaps it needs to be repeated all over again in other forms.

Comment: Yup, if it's a single thing and it's not going to be reused you can simply use the `Callback` constraint and validate everything inside the form.